# Azure Storage Blob Lifecycle Management Role to Edit/Add rules

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I can't find documentation on what roles allow edit of storage lifecycle management?
This is in the portal under Data Management --> Lifecycle Management, for Storage accounts.

Is it Contributor? Storage Blob Data Owner?

It may be this, but I want to be sure:
[image: contributor storage account perms]

Comment: You can use Contributor or Storage Account Contributor role to create storage account management policies for Life Cycle Management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Contributor** or **Storage Account Contributor** role to create storage account management policies for Life Cycle Management

The Contributor role can read, add or edit rules in the Azure Storage Life Cycle Management. Similarly, Storage Account Contributor role also have the same permissions for Azure Storage Life Cycle Management.

Contributor role grants full access to manage all the resources whereas Storage Account Contributor role grants access to manage the storage accounts.

In your case, you can use **Storage Account Contributor** role

[image]